# 3.32 text annotations

Tags: qgis

Is there another way hide and unhide text annotations in the QGIS version 3.32? I found it (ctrl + t)  to be one of the more useful parts of text annotation for the work I do but we updated the program and it no longer works.

Comment: Are you looking for keyboard shortcuts? [This](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/fi/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#:~:text=Keyboard%20shortcuts,-QGIS%20provides%20default&text=You%20can%20find%20them%20in,keyboard%20shortcuts%20to%20QGIS%20features.) might help you.